# Jquery Autocomplete for email

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I Attempting to do the autocomplete on a textbox which will contain all the recipient username. The username is delimit by semicolon ";" and the id for the textbox is "givenId".

Below is my design of the textbox:

Here is my jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $("#givenId").autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("MVCfunction")',
    });
});
```

My problem is now:

1) I had selected "jason" at the first place.

2) Then when I tried to select second user:

3) It Replaced the jason to kristy.

My question is how do i append to the textbox instead of replace the user once I select a new user?

My Expected Result is :

[image: Expected Result]

**EDIT ON 23/1/2015***

***Found a solution based on the demo given by @Stephen Muecke, check the answer below. :)**

Comment: Have you looked at the code in the [demo](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple)? Some further examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199182/jquery-ui-autocomplete-multiple-values-in-textbox)

Comment: How do I put the Url.Action into the demo?

Comment: Have a look at [this demo](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote)

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, It working now I will update this post for those who need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution I had found based on demo given by @Stephen Muecke.

This answer is used for MVC auto-complete with multiple value.

1)Remain this code on the script.

```
$(function () {
        $("#givenId").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("MVCfunction")',
        });
    });
```

2) And add these code below:

**[Note: this code is retrieved from http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple
 ]**

```
function split(val) {
        return val.split(/;\s*/);
    }
    function extractLast(term) {
        return split(term).pop();
    }


    $("#givenId")
      // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
      .bind("keydown", function (event) {
          if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
              $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
              event.preventDefault();
          }
      })
      .autocomplete({
          minLength: 0,
          source: function (request, response) {
              // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
              response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
          },
          focus: function () {
              // prevent value inserted on focus
              return false;
          },
          select: function (event, ui) {
              var terms = split(this.value);
              // remove the current input
              terms.pop();
              // add the selected item
              terms.push(ui.item.value);
              // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
              terms.push("");
              this.value = terms.join(";");
              return false;
          }
      });
});
```